# Is there a way in VBA to add a ListRow object and specify the columns by name?

Tags: vba, listobject

I have a table called "Names" like this

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Pete | 5 |
| Hugo | 1 |

and would like to add new data point, let's say "Malcolm, 9".

I can do it like this:

```
Sub addName()

Dim tbl as Listobject: Set tbl = Range("Names").ListObject
With tbl.ListRows.Add
    .Range(1) = "Malcolm"
    .Range(2) = 9
End With

End Sub
```

For the sake of flexibility, changing column order, inserted columns and the like, I would like to do it like this:

```
Sub addName()

Dim tbl as Listobject: Set tbl = Range("Names").ListObject
With tbl.ListRows.Add
    .Range("Name") = "Malcolm"
    .Range("Value") = 9
End With

End Sub
```

Is there a way in VBA to achieve this easily? There is a workaround in which you check the table header first, and look for the position of the column name. But that is overly tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this not-so-tedious workaround will do the trick. You need to insert two more lines.

```
Sub addName3()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim clm1 As Integer
Dim clm2 As Integer

Set tbl = Range("Names").ListObject

clm1 = tbl.ListColumns("Name").Index
clm2 = tbl.ListColumns("Value").Index


With tbl.ListRows.Add
    .Range(clm1) = "Malcolm"
    .Range(clm2) = 9
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great workaround. Easily maintainable, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in solution for this as far as I am aware.

You can of course create your own helpers though:

```
Sub Main()
  Dim row as object: set row = CreateDict("Name", "Malcolm, "Age", 20)
  row("height") = "5'7"
  'later
  Call addRow(myListObject, row)
End Sub

Function addRow(Byval lo as ListObject, ByVal oRow as object) as Boolean
  On Error GoTo ErrorOccurred
  Dim keys as variant: Keys = oRow.keys()
  Dim v() as variant: Redim v(1 to 1, 1 to lo.listcolumns.count)
  Dim iKey as long
  For iKey = 0 to ubound(keys)
    Dim sKey as string: sKey = keys(iKey)
    On Error GoTo lcDoesntExist
      v(1,lo.listcolumns(sKey).index) = oRow(sKey)
    On Error GoTo 0
lcDoesntExist:
  next
  lo.ListRows.Add.Value = v
ErrorOccurred:
End Function

Function CreateDict(ParamArray Params()) as Object
  Dim o as object: set o = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim i as long
  For i = 0 to ubound(params) step 2
    if isObject(params(i+1)) then
      set o(params(i)) = params(i+1)
    else
      let o(params(i)) = params(i+1)
    end if
  next
  set CreateDict = o
End Function
```

This code is untested and may have some issues.